# Bootstrap UI disturbance when using SELECT in Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to put a form field into Bootstrap's table classes and all was going well until I added a SELECT element to the form the bad juju crept in. Now -- while the form still works and kind of renders "ok" -- there are weird visual artefacts littered vertically at the horizontal start and end points of the aforementioned select dropdowns.

The example can be seen here: [[example]](http://jsfiddle.net/ksnyde/w9PqC/3/embedded/result/). You have to click the button to get the modal control up and then scroll down vertically a bit to see the offending SELECT fields.

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome. Can you maybe post a screenshot of the visual artifacts that you describe? You can use the free [imgur](http://imgur.com/) service to upload images. Just include a link to your image in your question.

Comment: Nothing in Firefox, either - apart from a dotted border around the dropdowns, is that what you meant? Which browser did you use?

Comment: Strange. I'm using Chrome on Mac. Here's a screen shot of what I see: http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/6934071534/

Comment: I have now tested it on Firefox (for Mac) and Safari (also Mac) and neither of these browsers seems to exhibit this behaviour. Does seem like a bug though ... probably in Chrome for Mac but maybe in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a defect in the rendering engine in Chrome for Mac. It doesn't appear in Windows Chrome or on Mac on Firefox or Mac Safari. Based on this I'm going to consider this closed.